# Action method is not fired after deploying in IIS using Ajax.ActionLink()

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, actionresult

I have a default routing as below:

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "URLParameter.Optional" }  // Parameter defaults
        );

    }
```

My Index Action method is returning a list of model to view. And in Index View i have somthing like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(article.Title,"Download",new { id = "C:\\Files\file1.txt"},null);
```

But, AFter deploying in IIS the "Download" action method is not getting fired And getting a 404 PAGE NOT FOUND error.

If I am specifing the action method as 'Index" in Html.ActionLink, Then It's working Like:

> @Html.ActionLink(article.Title,"Index",new { id = "C:\Files\file1.txt"},null);

The Above code is working because it's taking the default route after deploying in IIS. I tried to change the routes in Global.asax, But failed to get a solution.

What i need here is, I want the second action method to be fired, which is not.

My 1st Action Method is :

```
 public ActionResult Index() {}
```

My 2nd Action Method is :

```
  public ActionResult Download(string loc) {}    //This is not getting fired..???
```

Will provide you more details if needed..please Assist, as it will effect my delivery.

Comment: Have you tried changing the parameter in your ActionLink from id = "..." to loc = "..."

Comment: Ya I tried, It didn't worked. I created a new controller and pasted all the code inside the 'Actionresult Download' to 'Index' action method od new controller, As weel as created another route i.e. one with parameter with is mentioned above                                                                                                    and another with out parameter option: ex:                     routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                  
            "{controller}/{action}",                           
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"});}

Comment: In local machine its working fine.....when when iam deploying this to IIS, its doesn't. When placed the mouse on the hyperlink, its is creating a link as 'machinename/Home/Download?loc=url-->not working. If specifing the action method as Index in @Html.ActionLink, Its creting an hyperlink as 'machinename?loc=url.--->Woking Perfectly only if specifying the Action method as Index in @html.ActionLink().

Comment: Having a very similar problem, wish this question had an answer.